# Don't understand when I use objects as parameters in method

Tags: java, object, methods, parameters

Just got to part where I need to learn how to pass objects as parameters in method. I got little bit confused with this and need your help. Before this I have learned about method and constructor overloading. Here is the code:

```
class Test {
    int a, b;

    Test(int i, int j) {
        a = i;
        b = j;
    }

    // returns value true if object is equal to object which called method
    boolean equals(Test o) {
        if (o.a == a && o.b == b) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


public class ProslediObjekat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test ob1 = new Test(100, 22);
        Test ob2 = new Test(100, 22);
        Test ob3 = new Test(-1, -1);

        System.out.println("ob1 == ob2: " + ob1.equals(ob2));
        System.out.println("ob1 == ob3: " + ob1.equals(ob3));

    }
}
```

I understand that we first created three objects and gave them some values.
Then part which confuse me is part when we make this `Test o` parameter. I have never used object as parameter so I don't understand how we made this object? I just know this object is parameter.  **Need help to understand what is happening in this part (Test o)**

Then, this part: `ob1.equals(ob2)`, values `a`, and `b` has values which are set by constructor and `o.a` and `o.b` has values that are sent as parameters from object `ob2` right? And then if statement has to check if these two values are same. Right?

Comment: Have a look at some Java equals tutorials, e.g. http://www.java2blog.com/2014/02/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java.html to get a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that we first created three objects and gave them some values. Then part which confuse me is part when we make this Test o parameter. I have never used object as parameter so i don't understand how we made this object ? I just know this object is parameter.  Need help to understand what is happening in this part (Test o)

The below code has comments added to it for further understanding.

```
// returns value true if object is equal to object which called method
boolean equals(Test o) //takes in object o of type Test as parameter
{
    if(o.a == a && o.b == b) //if member data a, b of parameter object is equal to calling object's value a, b.
    {
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
   }
}
```

> Then, this part: ob1.equals(ob2), values a and b has values which are set by constructor and o.a and o.b has values that are sent as parameters from object ob2 right?

Correct, unless the values were never initialized, for example `Test t4`.

> And then if statement has to check if these two values are same. Right?

Yes.

Comment: I understand everything you just wrote me. But could you please explain me this part :  (Test o) we made new parameter here which is object right ?  It is same like we do with variables ( int o) The only difference is when we create object our Type is name of our class which is in this case Test ?

Comment: "O'Reilly's Java in a Nutshell by David Flanagan puts it best: 'Java manipulates objects by reference, but it passes object references to methods by value.'" So copies are made of `ob2` and `ob3` in your main program. An object will always have at least two references, then, when you pass it into a method.

Comment: This confuse me what you said a little bit, but i hope i will understand as long as i keep learning about OOP and objects. Thanks also for book, i will search for it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: We made a new parameter called `o` of type `Test` that has function `equals(Test)` scope. However, `o` refers to the parameter passed in, such as `obj2`.